# How to use $dayOfYear aggregation with epoch timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have my documents in this format:

```
{
    "_id": 1517209200000,       
    "timestamp": 1517209200000,
    "current": 236078,
}
```

Timestamp is an epoch representation of a date, with about 100 documents inserted per day. It's stored as a number.

I'm trying to figure out how to print last 30 days with average `$current` as well as min and max for each day.

I found the $dayOfYear aggregation however I am not sure how to apply it to my epoch timestamps.
(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/)

Could anyone share their knowledge if they know the answer?

Thank you

EDIT: my first attempt that returns an error: `"errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type double to Date",`

```
db.cable23.aggregate([ { $match: {'direction': 0} },{$group : {'_id': {'$year': "$timestamp"}}}])
```

Comment: Timestamp you are storing as a `Date` type or any other?

Comment: storing as a number

Comment: Try `db.cable23.aggregate([ { $match: {'direction': 0} },{$group : {'_id': {'$year': { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$timestamp" ] }}}}])`

Comment: can you try by making it `Date` Type?
most probably my guess is, as timestamp is a number type. Mongo is unable to make query with that, while `$year` only deals with `Date` type things.

Comment: you mean re-fill whole database with a date type? The question is on how to avoid it.